# Selecting Rows Where Value Exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am currently making a site, which uses a scoring system based on criteria, along with additional notes. Each criteria has a score associated with it, and the score is displayed along with the product. The criteria linking is done through a "tag cloud" using an intermediate linking table. The issue is, I want to be able to select products which meet certain criteria(s), but when I try to do this, it changes the product score - that's the issue.

I am using the following code in Laravel's query builder. However, this is more of just a MySQL problem, so you can answer it in plain SQL if you'd like.

```
$products = DB::table('products')->
    select('products.name', 'products.scored', 'products.slug', DB::raw('(SUM(`hex_criteria`.`score`) + SUM(DISTINCT(`hex_additionalnotes`.`score`))) as score'))->
    leftjoin('criteria_linkings', 'products.id', '=', 'criteria_linkings.product_id')->
    leftjoin('criteria', 'criteria_linkings.criteria_id', '=', 'criteria.id')->
    leftjoin('additionalnotes', 'additionalnotes.product_id', '=', 'products.id');

if (Input::get('criteria')) {
    $products->where(function($query) {
        $crits = explode('-', Input::get('criteria'));

        $query->where('criteria.id', '=', $crits[0]);
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($crits); $i++) {
            $query->orWhere('criteria_id', '=', $crits[$i]);
        }
    });
}

$products = $products->
    orderBy('scored', 'DESC')->
    orderBy($arr[0], $arr[1])->
    groupBy('products.id')->
    paginate(12);
```

The following is the query produced:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["query"]=>
    string(550) "select `hex_products`.`name`, `hex_products`.`scored`, `hex_products`.`slug`, (SUM(`hex_criteria`.`score`) + SUM(DISTINCT(`hex_additionalnotes`.`score`))) as score

    from `hex_products`
    left join `hex_criteria_linkings` on `hex_products`.`id` = `hex_criteria_linkings`.`product_id`
    left join `hex_criteria` on `hex_criteria_linkings`.`criteria_id` = `hex_criteria`.`id` left join `hex_additionalnotes` on `hex_additionalnotes`.`product_id` = `hex_products`.`id` where (`hex_criteria`.`id` = ? or `criteria_id` = ?)
    group by `hex_products`.`id`
    order by `scored` DESC, `score` asc"
    ["bindings"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "18"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "13"
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, I want to select products which have a certain criteria, without changing its score. Any ideas to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What is the SQL produced? You can check it doing `var_dump(DB::getQueryLog())`.

Comment: I've added it, see above